# secure docker prometheus container with ssl certificate?

Tags: docker, ssl, container

I want to secure docker prometheus container with ssl certificate. the problem is prometheus container dosn't have nginx or apache2 webserver to put certificate into their configuration folder.
so what shuld i do?
any suggestion will be appreciated .

Comment: You might be able to find better places to get an answer, since this is not strictly related to Ubuntu. However, I would suggest that you look into a reverse proxy solution, like [nginx proxy](https://nginxproxymanager.com/) or [traefik proxy](https://traefik.io/traefik/) - do some research on those.

Comment: thank you. nginx reverse proxy is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

create a web.yml file and add this configuration

```yml
tls_server_config:
  cert_file: /etc/prometheus/prometheus.crt # place of the cert file inside the docker container
  key_file: /etc/prometheus/prometheus.key # place of the key file inside the docker container
```

In the prometheus.yml file add this part

```yml
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'prometheus'
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['example.com:443']  # Replace with your SSL-enabled endpoint
    scheme: https  # Use HTTPS
    tls_config:
      cert_file: '/etc/prometheus/prometheus.crt'  # Path to your SSL certificate file
      key_file: '/etc/prometheus/prometheus.key'  # Path to your private key file
```

Then run the prometheus docker container as this

```bash
docker run -d \
  --name prometheus \
  -p 9090:9090 \
  prom/prometheus \
  --config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml \
  --web.config.file=/etc/prometheus/web.yml
```

Change the paths of the files according to your environment.